# Pure-Java vs Native SQLiteJDBC driver and Nested VM

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, native

I currently am working on a quite simple projet using Java web app hosted in Weblogic and an SQLite DB. (Scope quite small, two tables only)

Developpement went fine and still works, but when deploying to staging, i got some unexpected prolem.

Whenever the app has to read (select) from the DB, i can read the following stack trace :

```
Root cause of ServletException.java.lang.Error:  in _syscall()
    at org.ibex.nestedvm.Runtime.syscall(Runtime.java:1086)
    at org.sqlite.SQLite.run_0x171800(target/build/SQLite.mips:???)
    at org.sqlite.SQLite.trampoline(target/build/SQLite.mips:???)
    at org.sqlite.SQLite._execute(target/build/SQLite.mips:???)
    at org.ibex.nestedvm.Runtime.__execute(Runtime.java:506)
    at org.ibex.nestedvm.Runtime.call(Runtime.java:678)
    at org.ibex.nestedvm.Runtime.call(Runtime.java:647)
    at org.sqlite.NestedDB.call(NestedDB.java:568)
    at org.sqlite.NestedDB.call(NestedDB.java:563)
    at org.sqlite.NestedDB.prepare(NestedDB.java:130)
    at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:123)
    at org.sqlite.Stmt.executeQuery(Stmt.java:121)
```

Please tell me if i am wrong, but what i understand is that the target/build/SQLite.mips refers to a native implementation of the driver. However, i did specify it should stick to pure java using :

```
Connection con;

//Load the JDBC driver class dynamically.
Driver d = (Driver)Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC").newInstance();
DriverManager.registerDriver(d);

//init the connection
System.setProperty("sqlite.purejava", "true");          
con = DriverManager.getConnection(getConnectionString());
```

Is my understanding correct ? How could i further enforce the use of pure java implementation ?
Could anything else cause such a stack trace ?

For the record, both dev and stagging environements are linux / bea weblogic.

Thanks for you time :)

Comment: Why are you using SQLite and not, say, H2?

Comment: The team had little experience in embedded DB. SQLite was most know to us. Plus, our company policies are strict, and to go for full oracle by default. Was hard for us to obtain approval for SQLite, imagine about something a slightly less known to them...

Comment: Do you set this property before loading the JDBC driver? Otherwise you might want to try setting it when invoking the JVM with `-Dsqlite.purejava=true`

Comment: I just edited my question to show more code arround the setProperty. I'll try to see if i can alter the toolchain starting up weblogic. However, i can telle i did not put this setting on JVM start up for developement environement

Comment: Please see my answer. You are supposed to set the property _before_ the driver is loaded

Comment: The issue i identitifed was nopt the good one. Issue came from an NFS mis-configuration.

Answer (score 1):

From the class names in your stacktrace I am assuming that you are using XerialJ JDBC driver (isn't that a little old?)

According to its [wiki](http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/browser/XerialJ/trunk/sqlite-jdbc/SQLiteJDBC.wiki) you are supposed to set that property before loading the JDBC driver

```
System.setProperty("sqlite.purejava", "true");
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
```

You are setting it *after* the driver is loaded (but before connection setup). Please change the order of your initialization as below and retry:

```
//Load the JDBC driver class dynamically.
System.setProperty("sqlite.purejava", "true");          
Driver d = (Driver)Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
DriverManager.registerDriver(d);

//init the connection

con = DriverManager.getConnection(getConnectionString());
```

Comment: I'm trying this and i'll let you know as soon as something gets out of it :) Is it that old ? anyways, project is not a young one, and i keep reworking 1998-2005 java or VB classes

Comment: @Gruck I haven't used it to be honest but I was surprised that I only got svn repositories in the first results in google instead of an official page (while its parent project [xerial](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) has an official page)

Comment: Seems like it didn't change much. same behavior.

Comment: @Gruck As I understand now the NestedDB is the pure java implementation. "Pure" here means that it does not call native directly but instead call NestedVM that has transformed C/C++ code to Java binary code (??) I still think though that native calls will be done at some level. Anyway I am sorry I can't help further. [NestedVM](http://nestedvm.ibex.org/) documentation has broken links, so I am not sure how this whole setup works

Comment: Thanks anyway for your time already. Tried to add the option at JVM startup, didn't change much.

Answer (score 0):

As said in comment here is what we figured out.

Even though it is clearly stated NFS and SQLite don't mix up well together, the limited write operations and the need of concurent reading access from 3 machines force us to mix the two.

Problem was a service in charge of concurent access of file sharde via NFS being missing. Dev env had it running, staging didn't.

Thanks all for your time !